# How to move the camera diagnoally far away?

Tags: camera

When the camera is at the white position (the default position when you create a new Blender file), how can I move the camera to the red position, while seeing the same place? I know I can press `g` to move the camera, but none of the "x", "y", or "z" axis will do this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Move on Local Axis

You should double tap the <kbd>Z</kbd> key in order to move the camera in its **local** axis.

So the key sequence is <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> again.

Comment: .. _if_ the Transform orientation is set to 'Global'. If it's set to anything else, GZZ reverts the orientation to Global... I think I preferred it the old way ...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to grabbing on the local Z axis would be to go into camera view with <kbd>Num 0</kbd>, entering **View Navigation** with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (in 2.8+) or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (in previous versions), then using <kbd>S</kbd> to fly backwards.

This has the added benefit of being able to look around with the mouse at the same time and adjust horizontal positioning with <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>, though that may be undesirable if you don't wish to rotate the camera and accidentally move the mouse.